# adding widget dynamically into kivy screen object

Tags: python, kivy

As far as I am aware, kv language is useful when making a static display, e.g. not when making game which need much widget's positioning during runtime. Here I try to make a simple game, but still need much positioning, so kv language is out of context for the widget, but not for the screen. I use screen to differentiate the main menu and game screen. But when I try to use 'add_widget' to insert my image, it always positioned at the middle of the window. Later I found out that the screen size is only 100x100.

Below are the only way that I can thought of, but still with no luck:

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class GameScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation=Builder.load_file('ProjectSD.kv')

class ProjectSDApp(App):
    def build(self):
        A=presentation
        A.screens[0].size=(Window.size)
        A.screens[0].add_widget(Label(text='hello',font_Size=80,pos=(0,0)))
        return A

if __name__=='__main__':
    print(Window.size)
    ProjectSDApp().run()
```

and my ProjectSD.kv file:

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    HomeScreen:
    GameScreen:
<Button>:
    font_name:'attackofthecucumbers.ttf'

<HomeScreen>:
    name:'home'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'nature.jpg'
    Label:
        text: 'Monopoly GX'
        font_name:'KBDunkTank.ttf'
        font_size:100
        size_hint:0.7,0.2
        pos:root.width*0.15,root.height*0.70
    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = "game"
        text: 'Play Game'
        font_size:root.width/20
        size_hint:0.3,0.15
        pos:root.width*0.35,root.height*0.45
    Button:
        on_release: app.stop()
        text: 'exit'
        font_size:root.width/20
        size_hint:0.3,0.15
        pos:root.width*0.35,root.height*0.20

<GameScreen>:
   name:'game'
   Button:
      on_release: app.root.current = "home"
      background_color: (1,0.15,0.2,0.8)
      text: 'X'
      font_size:root.width/40
      size_hint:0.05,0.05
      pos:root.width*0.95,root.height*0.95
```

Since there is no 'pos' method in screen object, I put my widget to position (0,0) manually.

The only way I found is just below:
https://kivyspacegame.wordpress.com/2014/08/10/tutorial-flappy-ship-part-2-build-simple-menus-and-animate-your-games-using-clock/

So my question is, if I use screen object from kivy's build in, how to achieve the same result? So I can still adding and remove widget as I want it later?

Comment: Could you edit your question to be more specific about what you're asking?  Are you trying to add an image to an existing screen?  As a background (i.e. a canvas for another widget)?  Add a screen to a screen manager?  A Screen should be used to hold other layouts which themselves can hold things like images.  Also please post more code, a MCVE - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry for that, what I want to do is adding image, or anything to an existing screen,which screen is made with kivy's build in from python. my real problem is that the screen size is only 100x100. And not as background, but as an object that can be moved later

Comment: what are the contents of your kv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking; I don't see anywhere in your code where you are trying to add an Image to a Layout.  You add a label to the middle and that works fine.

I think because you are creating screens without any layouts and not setting a default window size, that the screens just take up their minimum default size.  You need to add a layout and fill it with stuff that has a defined size, or set a window size at the beginning e.g:

```
# window import
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
Window.size = (1920/2,1080/2)
Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex('#000000') # black
```

Here is some code that creates your two `Screen`s, and adds a draggable and a static `Image` at a position to a `FloatLayout`.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import (ScreenManager, Screen)
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class GameScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MovingImage(DragBehavior,Image):
    pass

class DragLabel(DragBehavior, Label):
    pass

class StaticImage(Image):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        A = ScreenManagement()
        A.current = 'game'
        A.screens[1].ids.gamefloat.add_widget(MovingImage(size_hint = [0.3,0.3]))
        A.screens[1].ids.gamefloat.add_widget(StaticImage(pos = (150,300)))
        return A

if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

and the .kv file called myapp.kv

```
<ScreenManagement>:
    HomeScreen:
    GameScreen:

<Button>:

<HomeScreen>:
    name:'home'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'image.jpg'
    Label:
        text: 'Monopoly GX'
        font_size:100
        size_hint:0.7,0.2
        pos:root.width*0.15,root.height*0.70
    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = "game"
        text: 'Play Game'
        font_size:root.width/20
        size_hint:0.3,0.15
        pos:root.width*0.35,root.height*0.45
    Button:
        on_release: app.stop()
        text: 'exit'
        font_size:root.width/20
        size_hint:0.3,0.15
        pos:root.width*0.35,root.height*0.20

<GameScreen>:
    name:'game'
    FloatLayout:
        id: gamefloat
        Button:
            on_release: app.root.current = "home"
            background_color: (1,0.15,0.2,0.8)
            text: 'X'
            font_size:root.width/40
            size_hint:0.05,0.05
            pos:root.width*0.95,root.height*0.95

<MovingImage>:
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 1000000
    drag_distance: 0
    source: 'image.jpg'

<StaticImage>:
    source: 'image.jpg'
```

Comment: I just made a simple code with label for example here. Both of them are widget, so isn't it basically the same?